# reading and storing an non determined matrix from textfile

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;
   int n = 0;
   char array[10][10];
   int i=0,j=0;
   fp = fopen("g.txt","r");
   if(fp == NULL) 
   {
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   do
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) )
      {
         break ;
      }
    if(c=='\n'){
     array[i][j]=c;
     i++;
     j=0;
    }
    j++;

   }while(1);

   fclose(fp);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf("%c ",array[i][j]);}
    printf("\n"); }

   return(0);
}
```

Hello, I am trying to get a matrix from a text file(character matrix specifically and wants to store in dynamic array(I know it is not dynamic in my example but for know i just try to do in determined matrix) . But my code doesn't work as it should.

I am trying to put all characters from matrix to my array and determine if character is '\n' then in next loop go for next row and init column to zero.

In theory it should seems to work but it prints bunch of nonsense symbols and doesn't seems to work correctly.
Which parts im mistaking ?

EDIT My text file to test :

```
Hello, I am trying to get a matrix from a text file(character matrix specifically and wants to store in dynamic ar
ray(I know it is not dynamic in 
my example but for know i just try to do in determined matrix) . But my code doesn't work as it should.
```

It doesnt fully prints correctly. Like sho prints out but "ul" doesnt. d does in new row.(linux terminal)

how it prints out = [http://imgur.com/a/7WYgs](https://imgur.com/a/7WYgs)

Comment: You don't seem to be setting anything in the array if the character is not `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change this part:

```
if(c=='\n'){
  array[i][j] = c;
  i++;
  j = 0;
}
```

To

```
if(c=='\n'){
  i++;
  j = 0;
} else {
  array[i][j] = c;
  j++;
}
```

This means that if the character is a new line, move to the next row, otherwise save it in the array.

Comment: Ah my mistake yes i fixed that quickly but thing is even this  works for most part it doesnt print some of words (specifically end letters ) I have a text file like this
"Hello, I am trying to get a matrix from a text file(character matrix specifically and wants to store in dynamic ar
ray(I know it is not dynamic in 
my example but for know i just try to do in determined matrix) . But my code doesn't work as it should.

"
It prints out "sho" and next printed out letter is "d"  it doesnt print out "ul" . Also same for  sentence too

Comment: Could you add the text file sample to your question.

Comment: i added my text file and how it prints out to my first Post.

Comment: You're creating a 10x10 array, maybe you need to make it bigger?

Comment: I created a 150x150 one that image example. still prints out same
http://imgur.com/a/lm4mF

Comment: Are you sure j is incremented correctly? I edited the answer to include that. I tried your code here http://ideone.com/MG7NvN and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You only store something in the array when you encounter a newline.

I would rewrite the loop to

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if(c!='\n'){
     array[i][j]=c;
     j++;
    }
    else
    {
      i++;
      j = 0;
    }
}
```

fgetc returns EOF on feof() AND ferror() so you wont have an infinite loop if there is a harddisk problem.